# Scrollbar but not scrolling on arrows

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, scrollbar, arrows

I want to keep my scroll bar and off its scrolling **only** on Arrow..

I tried to insert it to div `overflow: scroll` and then to  second div  `overflow: hidden` inside first..
but it doesn't work

**Any idea? **

Comment: Can you show us your html and css code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to prevent scrolling with arrows,

```
// add keyboard events
                    $( document ).keydown( function(e) {
                        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which,
                            arrow = {
                                left : 37,
                                up : 38,
                                right : 39,
                                down : 40,
                                escape : 27
                            };

                        switch (keyCode) {
                            case arrow.up:
                                e.preventDefault();
                                }
                           case arrow.down:
                                e.preventDefault();
                                }
                                break;
```

Comment: just add call to your function after e.preventDefault(); Or add e.preventDefault(); where you catch key event